# YouTube stats are not working properly when views are generated inside social network vk.com

Tags: statistics, youtube-api

please help us with the following problem.
YouTube statistics don't count all views generated inside vk.com social network.
For example, this video - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUpwC6ZxAA8- had more than 220,000 views on vk.com according to their statistics.
But your statistics says there were only 188,756 of them made on vk.com.
We know this because vk.com gathers its own stats using the YouTube API.
Could you please check this issue, and maybe you could write us a brief answer why it happens this way.
Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
 Anton